# tabularx inside a \newenvironment

Tags: tables, environments, tabularx

There's something wrong with this code:

```
\newenvironment{Tbl}
{\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|} \hline}
{\end{tabularx}}
```

but this is fine:

```
\newenvironment{Tbl}
{\begin{tabular}{|l|l|} \hline}
{\end{tabular}}
```

Why? And how can I get the first to work?

Here is the full LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newenvironment{Tbl}
{\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|} \hline}
{\end{tabularx}}

\begin{document}

\begin{Tbl}
\end{Tbl}

\end{document}
```

> `latex test.tex`

produces:

```
This is pdfTeXk, Version 3.141592-1.40.3 (Web2C 7.5.6)
 %&-line parsing enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2005/12/01>
Babel <v3.8h> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
yphenation, arabic, basque, bulgarian, coptic, welsh, czech, slovak, german, ng
erman, danish, esperanto, spanish, catalan, galician, estonian, farsi, finnish,
 french, greek, monogreek, ancientgreek, croatian, hungarian, interlingua, ibyc
us, indonesian, icelandic, italian, latin, mongolian, dutch, norsk, polish, por
tuguese, pinyin, romanian, russian, slovenian, uppersorbian, serbian, swedish, 
turkish, ukenglish, ukrainian, loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2005/09/16 v1.4f Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tools/tabularx.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tools/array.sty)) (./test.aux))
Runaway argument?
 \par 
! File ended while scanning use of \TX@get@body.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> test.tex

?
```

Comment: In the future please read the documentation of a package before asking a question on a package. This is clearly answered in the `tabularx` documentation.

Comment: @MartinSchröder This sort of attitude slows down progress. Because: it's much faster to type the error message into Google and get the answer on this site, than to read through the package documentation. Now multiply this by hundreds of people around the world. We're talking many hours saved.

Comment: The same issue occurs with the `tabulary` package, for which it is not documented. (You also really have to dig in the `tabularx` to find this issue described.) To help people find this question and solution, using `\tabulary` and `\endtabulary`, the error message is `! File ended while scanning use of \TY@get@body.`.

Answer (score 51):

This is considered "status by design" for [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx). See the [`tabularx` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/tabularx.pdf) (section **5 The Macros**, p 4).

The way around it is the use the "command form" of the `tabularx` environment:

```
\newenvironment{Tbl}
  {\tabularx{\textwidth}{|l|X|} \hline}
  {\endtabularx}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine in my LaTeX implementation, but I've had to add

```
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
```

in the preamble of my document.

Update: try adding content:

```
\begin{Tbl}
Hello & World \\
\end{Tbl}
```