# How can I create a wrapper environment for a complicated usage of tabularx?

Tags: environments, tabularx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [tabularx inside a \newenvironment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42325/tabularx-inside-a-newenvironment)

I know (at least basically) how to create my own environments using `\newenvironment`, but I recently encountered a problem trying to create an environment based on the `tabularx` environment. I had a complicated `tabularx` that was going to be repeated often, and I wanted to make an environment wrapper to save me time should I need to modify some aspect of this layout. For example,

```
\newenvironment{myspecialtable}{\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{r p{3in} X r}}{\end{tabularx}}
```

I get an error message when I try to use this environment. Can anyone tell me why this will not work?