# tabularx in newenvironment: Illegal pream-token

Tags: tables, environments

The following example gives:

> ! Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (\AtEndOfPackage): `c' used.

What is wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newenvironment{mytab}{
  \begin{tabularx}{5cm}{l}
  }{
  \end{tabularx}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{mytab}
  foo \\
  bar
\end{mytab}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does it work with `\tabularx` instead of `\begin{tabularx}` and `\endtabularx` instead of `\end{tabularx}`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [`tabularx` inside a `\newenvironment`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42325/5764)

Comment: I've seen [the other question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42325/tabularx-inside-a-newenvironment). However, the error message is different, and also I would like to understand *the why.*

Comment: With `\tabularx` and `\endtabularx` it works.

Comment: you are also missing `%` at the ends of lines `{mytab}{%%%` and `\end{tabularx}%%%%` otherwise you will get extra white space around the table. As documented in the package documentation this is same as AMS `align` etc the environment needs to look ahead and grab the whole environment, so the end code can not be hidden in a macro.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I noticed that `}{%` is enough to get rid of extra white space.

Comment: as written there would be a space after the table as well, but if you have already changed to `\endtabularx` then white space is ignored after a command name