# Bottom hline in a tabularx wrapper environment

Tags: tables, environments, rules, tabularx

I want to define a wrapper environment for a table where one of the columns stretches to fill the available width. I'm using the `tabularx` package and its `X` column for that. As mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42325/tabularx-inside-a-newenvironment) and in the `tabularx` documentation, I need to use `\tabularx`…`\endtabularx` rather than `\begin{tabularx}`…`\end{tabularx}` in the definition of my environment, because `\tabularx` runs to the end of the enclosing environment.

So far so good, now I'd like to add horizontal rules at the top and bottom. When I comment out the bottom `\hline` in the environment definition, I get an error

```
! Misplaced \noalign.
\hline ->\noalign 
                  {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule \@height \arrayrulewidth \futurelet...
l.28 \end{mytable}
```

MWE (with the desired but problematic `\hline` commented out):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newenvironment{mytable}{%
  \tabularx{\textwidth}{lX}
    \hline%
    Name & Description \\
    \hline%
}{%
  %\hline%
  \endtabularx%
}

\begin{document}
Manually (working fine): \\
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
  \hline
  Name & Description \\
  \hline
  foo & This description is long. It is very long. It is more than one line long. It is automatically broken up into lines. \verb`\verb` works. \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\medskip
Wrapper environment (error with the bottom \verb`\hline`): \\
\begin{mytable}
  foo & This description is long. It is very long. It is more than one line long. It is automatically broken up into lines. \verb`\verb` works. \\
\end{mytable}
\end{document}
```

How can I make my environment automatically include a horizontal rule at the bottom of the table?

I don't mind switching from `tabularx` to something else. I'll want to use the environment both inline and in a float. It would be very annoying if `\verb` didn't work. At the moment, it's fine if page breaks inside the table are impossible but I'm likely to have to tackle at some point that as my tables get longer.

<sub>Bonus question: why is there so little space between each horizontal line and the text below, and how do I make the space decent — `\strut`</sub>

Comment: for the bonus question `\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it says in the tabularx doc, the principal restriction on the `\tabularx` `\endtabularx` form is that `\endtabularx` is the first token in the end code. So the behaviour you see is documented feature, not a bug.

However you could do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\makeatletter

\newenvironment{mytable}{%
  \let\savedtx\TX@endtabularx
  \def\TX@endtabularx{\toks@\expandafter{\the\toks@\\\hline}\savedtx}%
  \tabularx{\textwidth}{lX}
    \hline%
    Name & Description \\
    \hline%
}{%
  %\hline%
  \endtabularx%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Manually (working fine): \\
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
  \hline
  Name & Description \\
  \hline
  foo & This description is long. It is very long. It is more than one line long. It is automatically broken up into lines. \verb`\verb` works. \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\medskip
Wrapper environment (error with the bottom \verb`\hline`): \\
\begin{mytable}
  foo & This description is long. It is very long. It is more than one line long. It is automatically broken up into lines. \verb`\verb` works.
\end{mytable}
\end{document}
```