# singlespacing in table with no indent

Tags: tables, tabularx, line-spacing, etoolbox

I'm trying to make a table that is as wide as the textwidth singlespaced with `etoolbox`'s `\AtBeginEnvironment` but that somehow gets rid of the `\noindent` that I issued before.

```
\documentclass{report} 
\usepackage{array,setspace,booktabs,tabularx,etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabularx}{\singlespacing\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ @{} p{3em} X @{} } 
\toprule
  Table  & Example \\
  Table  & Example \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
```

Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Your issuing of `\singlespacing` the `\arraystretch` redefinition comes too late anyway.

Comment: @Werner Hmm, it does do it though, I mean the spacing. Only the indent. When I don't use `etoolbox` it's fine but where would I issue the `singlespacing` then?

Comment: Is the rest of your document not `\singlespacing`?

Comment: @Werner Yeah, the rest is doublespaced, sorry, I didn't put that in the MWE (it's in the class)

Comment: Even if you use `\noindent\singlespacing` the indent appears. You can put `\singlespacing\noindent` to again force a `\noindent`.

Comment: Oh I see, that works, thank you!   So it's the `\singlespacing` that causes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\singlespacing` ignores the use of `\noindent`. If you want to insert content as part of [`tabularx](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx), [redefine it as part of a new environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42331/5764):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{setspace,tabularx,lipsum}

\let\oldtabularx\tabularx
\let\endoldtabularx\endtabularx
\renewenvironment{tabularx}[2]
  {\singlespacing
   \noindent
   \oldtabularx{#1}{#2}}% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42331/5764
  {\endoldtabularx}

\begin{document}

\doublespacing
\lipsum[1]

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ @{} p{3em} X @{} } 
  \hline
  Table  & Example \\
  Table  & Example \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```