# Custom environment with parameter: You can't use `macro parameter character #' in vertical mode

Tags: environments

I want to define a new environment to display blocks of plain text in a titled box, with whitespace reproduced exactly. Something like this

```
\begin{PlainText}{My Title}
Foo
Bar
\end{PlainText}
```

I'm putting a definition together by gathering various tips, but it doesn't work.

```
\newenvironment{TextFile}[1]{\ttfamily}{\par}
{
    #1\\[1ex]
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{0.9\textwidth}|}
    \hline
    \\
}
{ 
    \\ \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular} 
    \end{center}
}
```

I only 80% understand how this is intended to work, I read the first line as meaning

> TextFile is a new environment which takes one parameter, within it the font is monospace and \par means retain whitespace like HTML <pre>

I get an error at the `#1\\[1ex]` line

```
 You can't use `macro parameter character #' in vertical mode.
```

When it works, it should look like this:

[image]

Comment: `\newenvironment{TextFile}[1]{\ttfamily}{\par}` is wrong, of course and 'plain' text could be difficult. You should rather think of a verbatim environment. And don't forget to accept answers to your other questions

Comment: The intented code is not making use of `#1`, even worse, it's outside of the environment definition

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definition of

```
\newenvironment{TextFile}[1]{\ttfamily}{\par}
{
    #1\\[1ex]
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{0.9\textwidth}|}
    \hline
    \\
}
{ 
    \\ \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular} 
    \end{center}
}
```

is wrong, at least the parts with `{ #1\\ }{...}`, which are surely meant as the real document body, not something outside after the `{\par}` statement which is the `end code` part of the environment.

This way `#1 ...` etc. is meant as typesetting after the environment definition which must fail unless the definition is wrapped itself in another command or environment.

```
\documentclass{article}



\newenvironment{TextFile}[1]{\ttfamily%
    #1 \\[1ex]
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{0.9\textwidth}|}
    \hline
    \\
}{% 
    \\ \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular} 
    \end{center}
    \par
}

\begin{document}

\begin{TextFile}{Foo}
Learning \LaTeXe\ is fun!
\end{TextFile}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Your definition doesn't work because `\newenvironment` has the following syntax:

```
\newenvironmnt{<envname>}[<parms>][<opt>]
  {<begin envname>}% \begin{<envname>}
  {<end envname>}% \end{<envname>}
```

You've used it with no optional arguments (so `[<opt>]` has been removed) but supplied four mandatory arguments instead of two (the two being `{<begin envname>}` and `{<end envname>}`). Any of the arguments specified in `[<parms>]` are only available within `{<begin envname>}`, yet you've attempted to use it inside the *third* mandatory argument, where it doesn't exist.

---

The following approaches ensure that the title and subsequent block stay together and fit within the text block width.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\newenvironment{TextFile}[1]
  {% \begin{TextFile}{#1}
   \par\ttfamily
   \noindent
   % http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42331/5764
   \tabularx{\linewidth}{|X|}
     \multicolumn{1}{c}{#1} \\[1ex]
     \hline \\
  }{% \end{TextFile}
     \\ \\
     \hline
    \endtabularx
    \par\medskip
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{TextFile}{My Title}
Foo \\
Bar
\end{TextFile}

\end{document}
```

Another option using [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstnewenvironment{TextFile}[1]
  {\lstset{
    basicstyle = \ttfamily,
    frame      = lrtb,
    title      = {\ttfamily #1}}}
  {}

\begin{document}

\begin{TextFile}{My Title}
Foo
Bar
\end{TextFile}

\end{document}
```