# Titlesec : Missing number, treated as zero AND Illegal unit of measure

Tags: titlesec

I'm new here and almost newbie to latex. Sorry for my English.

Environment: Miktex 4.1, TexnicCenter 2.02(64bit), mode: LaTeX=>PDF

I searched a lot. At first I searched for method to put chapters into a frame...
... and found this:

[background color in titlesec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/518841/background-color-in-titlesec)

It wasn't exactly what I've been looking for but decided to work with that.

Additional information: I have 4 chapters.

First attempt:

...

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\sffamily\bfseries}%
{}%
{}%
{\begin{adjustwidth}{-0.9in}{-0.8in}%
\tcbset{standard jigsaw,
    colback=ChapterBackColor,
    colframe=ChapterFrameColor,
    opacityback=0.1,
    arc=10pt,
    sharp corners=east,
    width=\linewidth-0.5in}%
\begin{tcolorbox}[rightrule=0mm,leftrule=3mm,toprule=1mm,bottomrule=0.5mm,flush right,halign=flush right,enlarge top by=-2.5cm,enlarge bottom by=1cm]%
\Large{}CHAPTER\huge{} \Roman{chapter}\strut\\[0.3ex] #1\end{tcolorbox}\end{adjustwidth}}
```

...

---

`E D I T`

Ok. Since my project contained tones of garbage, I needed to prepare ready-to-compile small samples for you.
And this way I located error having `vertical mode` in message. There is even nothing to talk about.

But there are still errors and believe I'm doing something wrong using `titleformat`. I have four chapters and four errors:

`! Missing number, treated as zero`

and four errors:

`! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)`

Code to compile:
...

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1.2in,right=0.8in,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{avant}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{ChapterFrameColor}{RGB}{222, 66, 44}
\definecolor{ChapterBackColor}{RGB}{255, 222, 111}
\definecolor{ChapterForeColor}{RGB}{ 55, 16, 11}
\definecolor{ListingFrameColor}{RGB}{200, 80, 50}
\definecolor{ListingBackColor}{RGB}{231, 227, 201}
\definecolor{ListingNumColor}{RGB}{251, 249, 241}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=black,bookmarksopen=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[
    open,
    openlevel=2,
    atend
]{bookmark}[2011/12/02]
\usepackage{tikz}
%
%
%
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
%
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\sffamily\bfseries}%
{}%
{}%
{%
%
\begin{adjustwidth}{-0.9in}{-0.8in}%
\tcbset{standard jigsaw,
    colback=ChapterBackColor,
    colframe=ChapterFrameColor,
    opacityback=0.1,
    arc=10pt,
    sharp corners=east,
    width=\linewidth-0.5in}%
%
\begin{tcolorbox}[rightrule=0mm,leftrule=3mm,toprule=1mm,bottomrule=0.5mm,flush right,halign=flush right,enlarge top by=-2.5cm,enlarge bottom by=1cm]%
\Large{}CHAPTER\huge{} \Roman{chapter}\strut\\[0.3ex]#1\end{tcolorbox}\end{adjustwidth}%
%
}
%
%
%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\tcbuselibrary{minted,skins}
\newtcblisting{mynumcpp}[1][]{listing engine=minted,
minted style=vs,
minted language=cpp,
minted options={fontsize=\small,breaklines,linenos,autogobble,numbersep=3mm,#1},
colback=ListingBackColor,colframe=ListingFrameColor,listing only,
left=7mm,enhanced,
overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[ListingNumColor] (frame.south west)
rectangle ([xshift=7mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}}}
%
\newtcblisting{mycpp}{listing engine=minted,
minted style=vs,
minted language=cpp,
minted options={fontsize=\small,breaklines,autogobble},
colback=ListingBackColor,colframe=ListingFrameColor,listing only,
enhanced}
%
\frenchspacing
\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}
\part{Part One}
\chapter{Some chapter}
\section{Section name A}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{mycpp}
int main() {
    printf("hello, world");
    return 0;
}
\end{mycpp}
\lipsum[3-4]
\chapter{Some other chapter}
\section{Section name B}
\lipsum[5-6]
\chapter{Chapter name}
\section{Section name C}
\lipsum[7-8]
\part{Part Two}
\chapter{4th chapter}
\section{Section name D}
\lipsum[5-6]

\end{document}
```

...

I can remove fragments with `minted` - if that would be a problem.

I don't know whether I should change a title of this topic or leave it as it is now.

---

`E D I T - 2`

`Solution` : Argument `<sep>` must be given.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348840/custom-environment-with-parameter-you-cant-use-macro-parameter-character-i

Comment: Are you loading `titlesec` with the `explicit` option?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you please post a compilable,from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`, loading the relevant packages? Also, please explain a bit which result you expect.

Comment: @jsbibra: thank you for edition. @egreg: yes. @Bernard: code pasted. Expected result is whole chapter title, so: chaptertitlename, chapter-number and chapter-caption inside `tcolorbox`.

Comment: The third mandatory argument to `\titleformat` *must* contain a length and cannot be left empty.

Answer (score 2):

The third mandatory argument to `\titleformat` has to contain a length, even if you need 0pt.

Here's a reorganized version of your preamble, with clear separation of package loading and settings.

In particular, I advise to use `babel` rather than `polski` (which does a bit of strange things) and `newtx` instead of `mathptmx`.

I load `titlesec` without `explicit`, which allows to prepare code suitable for both numbered and unnumbered chapters with no code duplication. The idea is that the chapter title is passed braced to the code of the last mandatory argument, so it will be treated as a trailing argument.

Using one line per option is, in my opinion, better in order to see more clearly what you have activated and to experiment with inactivating or changing a few of them.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1.2in,right=0.8in,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}

\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{avant}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted,skins}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=blue,
  urlcolor=black,
  bookmarksopen=true
]{hyperref}
\usepackage[
    open,
    openlevel=2,
    atend
]{bookmark}[2011/12/02]

\definecolor{ChapterFrameColor}{RGB}{222, 66, 44}
\definecolor{ChapterBackColor}{RGB}{255, 222, 111}
\definecolor{ChapterForeColor}{RGB}{ 55, 16, 11}
\definecolor{ListingFrameColor}{RGB}{200, 80, 50}
\definecolor{ListingBackColor}{RGB}{231, 227, 201}
\definecolor{ListingNumColor}{RGB}{251, 249, 241}

\titleformat{name=\chapter}[display]
  {\sffamily\bfseries}
  {}
  {0pt}%
  {\bombadilchapter{1}}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\sffamily\bfseries}
  {}
  {0pt}%
  {\bombadilchapter{0}}

\newcommand{\bombadilchapter}[2]{%
  \begin{adjustwidth}{-0.9in}{-0.8in}
  \begin{tcolorbox}[
    standard jigsaw,
    colback=ChapterBackColor,
    colframe=ChapterFrameColor,
    opacityback=0.1,
    arc=10pt,
    sharp corners=east,
    width=\linewidth-0.5in,
    rightrule=0mm,
    leftrule=3mm,
    toprule=1mm,
    bottomrule=0.5mm,
    flush right,
    halign=flush right,
    enlarge top by=-2.5cm,
    enlarge bottom by=1cm
  ]
  \ifnum#1=0
    \huge\strut\\[0.3ex]
  \else
    \Large \MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \huge\Roman{chapter}\strut\\[0.3ex]
  \fi
  #2%
  \end{tcolorbox}
  \end{adjustwidth}
}


\newtcblisting{mynumcpp}[1][]{
  listing engine=minted,
  minted style=vs,
  minted language=cpp,
  minted options={
    fontsize=\small,
    breaklines,
    linenos,
    autogobble,
    numbersep=3mm,
    #1,
  },
  colback=ListingBackColor,
  colframe=ListingFrameColor,
  listing only,
  left=7mm,
  enhanced,
  overlay={%
    \begin{tcbclipinterior}
      \fill[ListingNumColor] (frame.south west) rectangle ([xshift=7mm]frame.north west);
    \end{tcbclipinterior}%
  },
}

\newtcblisting{mycpp}{
  listing engine=minted,
  minted style=vs,
  minted language=cpp,
  minted options={
    fontsize=\small,
    breaklines,
    autogobble
  },
  colback=ListingBackColor,
  colframe=ListingFrameColor,
  listing only,
  enhanced,
}

\frenchspacing
\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}
\part{Part One}

\chapter*{Introduction}

\lipsum[1-2]

\chapter{Some chapter}
\section{Section name A}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{mycpp}
int main() {
    printf("hello, world");
    return 0;
}
\end{mycpp}
\lipsum[3-4]
\chapter{Some other chapter}
\section{Section name B}
\lipsum[5-6]
\chapter{Chapter name}
\section{Section name C}
\lipsum[7-8]
\part{Part Two}
\chapter{4th chapter}
\section{Section name D}
\lipsum[5-6]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your help and effort but i will stick to my solution because I understand it. You defined command `bombadilchapter`, called with one argument only and yet, you're using argument `#2` inside. I don't know how it works. I choose package `polski` because it was updated in 2016 and my sources are using this. But I've never used `polski` package before. What i don't know is why you removed `inputenc`. Normally I don't mix dependencies and defs/settings ... but this is a draft only.  Thank you.