# How to correctly wrap a tabularx inside a threeparttable?

Tags: tables, tabularx, package-writing, threeparttable

My question is basically in the title. I tried, but cannot get it to work, despite the [`threeparttable`](https://ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable) documentation explicitly claiming compatibility with [`tabularx`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx). Here is what I tried so far:

#### `main.tex`

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{testpack}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabxn}{label}{Caption}{Xr}{\textwidth}
  Head A      & Head B \\
  \midrule
  \lipsum[1]  & Something\tnote{a}
\tabxnotes
  \item[a] Some remark;
\end{tabxn}

\end{document}
```

#### `testpack.sty`

```
\ProvidesPackage{testpack}

\RequirePackage{float}
\RequirePackage{booktabs}
\RequirePackage{tabularx}
\RequirePackage[para,flushleft]{threeparttable}

\makeatletter%
\newcommand{\tabxnotes}{\bottomrule\end{tabularx}\begin{tablenotes}}%
\newenvironment{tabxn}[5][\fps@table]{%
  \expanded{\noexpand\begin{table}[#1]}%
    \label{tab:#2}%
    \caption{#3}%
    \begin{threeparttable}%
      \centering%
      \begin{tabularx}{#5}{#4}%
        \toprule%
}{%
      \end{tablenotes}%
    \end{threeparttable}
  \end{table}%
}%
\newcommand{\tabxnfile}[5][\fps@table]{%
  \begin{scitabxn}[#1]{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}%
    \input{tab/#2}%
  \end{scitabxn}%
}%
\makeatother%
```

#### `main.log` (excerpt)

```
Runaway argument?
 \par 
! File ended while scanning use of \TX@get@body.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> main.tex
```

I know this should tell me that I may have forgotten a closing brace, a `\end{env}` or something along those lines, but I haven't found anything by triple-checking. How can I get this to work, and if not, what is flawed about the way I approach this?

Edit: Tracing down the bug a bit further, it seems to be in the `\tabxnotes` command. When I substitute the command for its contents, the MWE compiles. However, to keep things [dry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), I would like to put that stuff inside one command, instead of three.

Comment: [tabularx inside a \newenvironment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42325/134144) might be interesting.

Comment: Now you are adding to my confusion. I constructed another MWE trying to pin down the problem. Using `\tabularx *table* \endtabularx` creates the same error, while `begin{tabularx} *table* \end{tabularx}` doesn't. Both in that case outside of the `tabxn` definition. I did however find out that even with the "working" version, the `\tabxnotes` command breaks it. What puzzles me the most though, is that three breaking examples give me the same error message.

Comment: please see the tabularx documentation, you need a different markup to include it in an environment definition.

Comment: you basically can not do this `\newcommand{\tabxnotes}{\bottomrule\end{tabularx}\begin{tablenotes}}%` you can define `tabularx` as par of another _environment_ but you can not start it with one command and end it with another, you _have_ to use an environment form.

Answer (score 2):

> Edit: Tracing down the bug a bit further, it seems to be in the `\tabxnotes` command.

You basically can not do this

```
\newcommand{\tabxnotes}{\bottomrule\end{tabularx}\begin{tablenotes}}%
```

You can define `tabularx` as part of another *environment* but you can not start it with one command and end it with another, you *have* to use an environment form.

Environments are a basic syntactic construct in latex and it is rarely a good idea to hide that syntax. But environments such as `tabularx` or AMS alignments such as `align` are special environment forms that require the environment syntax in order to grab the environment body.

Comment: Shouldn't it work then when using the `\tabularx ... \endtabularx` form?

Comment: @tillyboy no. It can not work (not without an unreasonable amount of effort patching things to look like an environment) You need to use the documented syntax, that's the point of the documentation.