# Tabularx doesn't compile as a command

Tags: compiling, tabularx

I have a 3 commands for my ease of access namely `resumeBulletStart`, `resumeBullet` and `resumeBulletEnd`. Compiling while using the commands fails. Although, when I copy the same content as sequential code, it compiles.

```tex
\documentclass[letterpaper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcommand{\resumeBulletStart}{
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| X | r |}
}
\newcommand{\resumeBullet}[2]{
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \small{#1}
        \item \small{#2}
    \end{itemize}
    & \small{\textit{#2}} \\
}
\newcommand{\resumeBulletEnd}{
    \end{tabularx}
}

\begin{document}
    \centering
    
    %%%% Using Command %%%%
    \resumeBulletStart
        \resumeBullet{one}{two}
    \resumeBulletEnd
    
    %%%% Not Using Command %%%%
    % \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| X | r |}
        
    %     \begin{itemize}
    %         \item \small{one}
    %           \item \small{one}
    %     \end{itemize}
    %     & \small{\textit{two}} \\
    
    % \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `tabularx` looks for the end of the current environment. You can wrap it in an environment like described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42325/82917 but it won't work like you are trying. You might do it with delimited arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment, I have solved my question. Shoutout to [@campa](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/82917/campa) and [this answer by @Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42331/231757) <3

```tex
\documentclass[letterpaper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcommand{\resumeBullet}[2]{
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \small{#1}
        \item \small{#2}
    \end{itemize}
    & \small{\textit{#2}} \\
}

\newenvironment{resumeBullets}
  {\tabularx{\textwidth}{| X | r |}}
  {\endtabularx}

\begin{document}
    \centering

    \begin{resumeBullets}
        \resumeBullet{one}{two}
    \end{resumeBullets}

\end{document}
```