# Nested tabularx inside a \newenvironment

Tags: tables, environments, tabularx

I would like to use `tabularx` in my own environment, but nested inside a `table` environment.

Please see my MWE below: I first produce the desired result without a custom environment. Then I try to accomplish the same output with my own environment. Alas that doesn't work:

When I switch from `tabular*` to `tabularx`, I get the compile error `File ended while scanning use of \TX@get@body.`. If I stay with `tabular*`, but switch the last column descriptor from `c` to `X`, I get another compile error: `Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. a & b &`.

In the answer to question [tabularx inside a \newenvironment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42325/tabularx-inside-a-newenvironment), one suggests to go for `\tabularx` and `\ endtabularx`, but that doesn't work in my case where `tabularx` is nested inside a `table` environment.

What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|c|X|}\hline
    a & b & tabularx \\\hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\newenvironment{MyTabular}{
  \begin{table}[!h]
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{|c|c|c|}\hline
    }{%
      \hline
    \end{tabular*}
  \end{table}
}

\begin{MyTabular}
  a & b & MyTabular \\
\end{MyTabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why would you use `table` if you don't add a caption? There's no law imposing that a `tabular` (or variant thereof) must live inside `table`.

Comment: The instruction `\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{|c|c|c|}` looks suspect for two separate reasons. First, you're not providing any mechanism that would enable LaTeX to achieve your goal of making the width of the `tabular*` environment equal `\textwidth`. Second, never use vertical rules in a proper `tabular*` environment. In short, I think you should replace `\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{|c|c|c|}` with `\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ccc @{}}`.

Comment: @egreg I provided a MWE. For that I needed a nested environment. In my real world document, tabularx is nested inside a table to which I do supply both a caption and a label ... both of which are totally unnessary in the context of my question. Hence MWE.

Comment: @Mico I provided a MWE that compiles and that demonstrates that either going for the column descriptor X or for tabularx in my custom environment breaks compilation. As indicated in my introduction, the aim is to use tabularx with X inside my custom environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tabularx` gathers everything up to the next `\end{⟨current environment⟩}`, and the name of the current environment is set up by `\begin{...}`. Therefore, if you do only

```
\newenvironment{MyTabular}{
  \begin{table}[!h]
    \tabularx{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|}\hline
    }{%
      \hline
    \endtabularx
  \end{table}
}
```

then `\begin{MyTabular}` will first save `MyTabular` as current environment name, but then `\begin{table}` changes the name of the current environment to `table`; `tabularx` tries to look up everything up to `\end{table}`, which it won't find, hence the errors.

You should use also `\table` and `\endtable`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newenvironment{MyTabular}[1][tbp]{% use !h as default only if you like pain
  \table[#1]
  \tabularx{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|}
  \hline
  }{%
   \\% <-- I'd put this here, so you don't have to close every tabular with \\
   \hline
   \endtabularx
   \endtable
}

\begin{document}

\begin{MyTabular}
  a & b & MyTabular
\end{MyTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT** After egreg's comment it came to me that you might be wanting to place the table where it is written in the code but you don't need a caption. In this case there is no need for a `table` environment, you can just use `center` (which adds a bit of space above and below).

```
\newenvironment{MyTabular}{%
  \center
  \tabularx{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|}
  \hline
  }{%
   \\% <-- I'd put this here, so you don't have to close every tabular with \\
   \hline
   \endtabularx
   \endcenter
}
```

Comment: The default placement should *never* be `!h`.

Comment: @egreg I agree but I don't feel entirely responsible for other people's bad habits `;-)` I'll add a comment.

Comment: +1 for your answer.

Comment: @egreg @campa I provided a MWE. `!h` puts both tables underneath each other at the top of the document. Otherwise they would have been spread of the page. I intentionally used `!h` for the sake of a nice MWE.

Comment: @campa Thanks for pointing out that `\begin{...}` has an influence on the `\newenvironment` command. This is crucial to know and hence to understand why the original approach was not working. This was the only answer I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @MarkusNißl `!h` is still wrong (and LaTeX will replace it by `!ht` automatically). Note that it is often unwise to not include `p` in the possible placements, as otherwise you might get your floats flushed to the end of the chapter/document.